# Dropdown animation icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Assuming I have a dropdown menu just like this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/1fb9nqb1/

```js
$('#toggle').click(function () {
    $('#dropdown').slideToggle();
    $('#opt-slide').toggleClass('open');
});

$('#dropdown > li').click(function () {
    $('#dropdown').slideUp();
    $('#opt-slide').removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
header {
    height:200px;
    background:#39F;
    z-index:4;
}
#opt-slide {
    width:300px;
}
#toggle {
    background:#099;
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    color:#FFF;
    line-height:50px;
    z-index:4;
}
#dropdown {
    background:#0C9;
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:0px;
    z-index:2;
    display:none;
}
#dropdown li {
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
}
#dropdown li:hover {
    background:#FAFAFA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="opt-slide"> <span id="toggle">OPTIONS</span>

    <ul id="dropdown">
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
        <li>Option 4</li>
        <li>Option 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

how can I add animation just like this one:

https://dribbble.com/shots/1621359-Open-Close-Icon-Animation
to support the expand / collapse of the menu?
another thing, is there any way to do the dropdown menu without jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/oxm9z6s3/), you'll see that I've added two spans `#s1` and `#s2`, with a container `div#sign`, the span is rotated `45deg` but opposite to each others, when the menu is hidden the two `spans` are position in a way representing an arrow shape, if you click on the toggle `span`, `.class1` and `.class2` are added to to `#s1` and `#s2` respectively, these classes has different `margin-left` values making the two spans forming the X-shape with transitio, where original `margin-left` valeus set in each span css with transition to make them moving in and out smoothly instead of just jumping all in css, you could however animate these spans with jquery `.animate()` setting same values with easing too but since it could be done with css I'd go with it:

**Edit-1:** Code changed upon a comment, changed `div#sign` to `span#sign` and made it a child of `span#toggle` [**JS Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/oxm9z6s3/1/)

*Updated Code*:

```js
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('#dropdown').slideToggle();
  $('#opt-slide').toggleClass('open');
  $('#sign #s1').toggleClass('close1');
  $('#sign #s2').toggleClass('close2');

});

$('#dropdown > li').click(function() {
  $('#dropdown').slideUp();
  $('#opt-slide').removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
header {
    height:200px;
    background:#39F;
    z-index:4;
}
#opt-slide {
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
}
#toggle {
    background:#099;
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    color:#FFF;
    line-height:50px;
    z-index:4;
    position:relative;
}
#dropdown {
    background:#0C9;
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:0px;
    z-index:2;
    display:none;
}
#dropdown li {
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
}
#dropdown li:hover {
    background:#FAFAFA;
}
#sign{
    width:50px;
    height:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    right:10px;
}
#sign .s{
    width:25px;
    height:4px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:2px;
    background-color:white;
    position:absolute;
}
#sign #s1{
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    z-index:100;
    margin-left:0;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
}
#sign #s2{
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    z-index:200;
    margin-left:16px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in;
}
#sign #s2.close2{
    margin-left:7px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
}
#sign #s1.close1{
    margin-left:7px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="opt-slide"> <span id="toggle">OPTIONS<span id="sign"><span id="s1" class="s"></span><span id="s2" class="s"></span></span>
  </span>

  <ul id="dropdown">
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
    <li>Option 4</li>
    <li>Option 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Umm, I didn't know that was needed too, just give me some time :)